# Latex glossary with glossaries package does not appear + adding more columns

Tags: latex, glossary

I tried to get a grip on the glossaries package and understood a bit of it, but now I am stuck and need your help to get any further. I have written the following piece:

```
%Dieses Dokument dient der Erprobung von Funktionen des Glossary-Pakages
%Packete, die vor glossaries geladen werden müssen
%Packete, die laut user-guide vor glossaries geladen werden müssen
%polyglossia wird ausgenommen
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Weitere Packete, die in IPA_Main aufgelistet werden
%Seitengestaltung und Literaturverwendung werden hier ausgespart
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 %hyperref muss als letztes vor glossaries geladen werden
\usepackage{hyperref}

%Anlegen des Glossares mit xindy
%Importieren des Packetes glossaries mit den folgenden Eigenschaften:
%Glossar wird mit der Software xindy angelegt, es werden Acronyme angelegt, der Name der Gruppierung 
wird angezeigt, die Einträge werden alphabetisch geordnet
\usepackage[xindy, acronyms, style=indexgroup, order=letter]{glossaries}
%hinzufügen eines weiteren glossares
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\makeglossaries
%Eintrag ins Hauptglossar
\newglossaryentry{Test1}
{
name = Test 1,
description = {Test eines Eintrages in ein Hauptglossar}
}
%Eintrag zu den Acronymen
\newacronym{t2}{t2}{Test eines Acronyms im Acronymverzeichnis}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries
\newpage
In diesem Satz wird der Eintrag \gls{Test1} ein erstes mal, dann eines zweites mal getestes 
\gls{Test1}.
\newline
Nun folgt der Test des angelegten Acronyms im Acronymverzeichnis \gls{t2}.

\end{document}
```

As far as the the definition goes, this seems to work. When using the acronym and the glossary-entry, the text in the pdf appears as desired without any error. But somehow, the glossaries do not get printed. I would like to ask what the reasons for that could be.
Also I would like to have a glossary that has the following 4 columns: Symbol\Description\Unit\page. I will have multiple glossaries, but the desired columns should appear only on one specific glossary. If anyone could show me how this could be done, I would be very thankfull.

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used these both options before, they might be improved, but they do what I want them to do:

### 1. with `glossary` package

I recommend this when the **focus** between the two acronym groups is between *pure mentioning of the acronym vs. some more details* on the definition. I had problems when I tried to use different glossaries as described in the CTAN package but the solution below worked out for me in the end.

I resolved it so, that my `glossary` is directly defined *in the `preamble`* of the `main.tex`

##### `glossary.tex`

```latex
\newglossaryentry{GOV}{name=Government, description={The system or group of 
     people governing an organized community, generally a state.},
     plural=Governments}
```

All acronyms are defined in an extra file

##### `acronyms.tex`

```latex
\newacronym{ngo}{NGO}{Non Governmental Organization}
```

Both definitions use the `glossary` package and this way the first got recognised as "main" glossary and therefore printed them separately.

#### `main.tex` preamble

```latex
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 
\input{glossary}
```

As I wanted them to be printed I need to add the following code

#### `main.tex` body

```latex
\begin{document}
...
    \printglossary[title={Glossary}, type=main]
    \input{acronyms} 
    \printglossary[title={Acronyms}, type=\acronymtype] 
...
\end{document}
```

To display the entries, I may delete all auxilary files including glossary related ones as they sometimes lead to compiling trouble.
then I execute:
a) `compile`
b) `makeglossaries`
c) `compile`
d) `view`
First Glossary, then acronyms are printed.

[image]
[image]

### 2. with `nomencl` package

I recommend this when working with lots of different acronyms like latin, greek and arabic letters with units and some indices and so on. This is more hacked bit ensures they all are listed in the desired order.

#### `main.tex` preamble

```latex
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
            \setlength{\nomitemsep}{.15\parsep}
            \newcommand\nomunit[1]{\def\nomentryend{\hfill#1}}
            \setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.25\hsize}
            \let\abbrev\nomenclature
            \renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature}
            \makenomenclature
            \usepackage{ifthen}
            \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
                \item[\bfseries
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\Large Latin Symbols}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{B}}{ \Large Greek Symbols}{%
                        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{C}}{\Large Indices}{%
                            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{D}}{ \Large Acronyms}{%
                                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{E}}{\Large Constants}{%
                }}}}} ]}
```

And then in a separate file the definitions

#### `nomenclature.tex`

```latex
\begin{document}
\nomenclature[B]{$\rho$}{Density \nomunit{$\mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}} $}}
\nomenclature[C]{$_{\mathrm{vib}} $}{Vibration}
...
\begin{document}
```

which is then called in the document space of e.g. the main.tex

#### `main.tex`

```
\begin{document}
...
\subfile{nomenclature}
...
\end{document}
```

Common error if the glossary does not appear: forgot to call `makeglossaries`